# Mongo $in with compound index

Tags: mongodb

How to efficiently do an `$in` lookup on a collection with a compound index?

Index is on fields a and b per example below. EG: `db.foo.createIndex({a: 1, b: 1})`

Example in SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE (a,b) 
  IN (
    ("aVal1", "bVal1"),
    ("aVal2", "bVal2")
  );
```

I know you can do something like:

```
db.foo.find( {
    $or: [
        { a: "aVal1", b: "bVal1" },
        { a: "aVal2", b: "bVal2" },
    ]
} )
```

Is there a more performant way to do this using the `$in` operator?

Comment: what are your indexes? whats a sample document? what leads you to believe `$in` is the better way?

Comment: @kmdreko Added index info to question. This `$or` syntax to look up thousands of records at a time seems to be much slower than doing an `$in` on a collection with a single field index. I was hoping for a more performant solution. 

A sample document is one that has both of these keys with the compound index and some other data (not sure how that other data is relevant to the question, but if it is let me know and I can add more details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already create a compound index for `(a, b)`, all of your clauses expression are supported by indexes -> mongo will use index scan instead of collection scan. It probably fast enough.

Reference: [$or Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes)

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will perform a collection scan.

Now about your question

> Is there a more performant way to do this using the $in operator?

`$in` match entire field. If you want to match `(a,b)` then obviously `(a,b)` must become an embedded object to search with `$in`.

Not sure if making embedded object fits your current schema / requirement. But if it is the case, [`$in` has known for better performance comparing to `$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in):

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or operator.

In this case, if you have embedded object like: `{e: {a: 'x', b: 'y'}}` then `db.collections.createIndex({e: 1})` paired with `$in` will speed things up