# Can I use $in statement for two fields instead of one in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I had a list of dictionaries that had one field called `unique_field_id` and I wanted to get each document for each item of this list.
One way was to do it with a for loop and calling `find_one()` query like this:

```
my_list = [{'unique_field_id': 1}, {'unique_field_id': 2}, {'unique_field_id': 3}]
document_list = list()

for el in my_list:
    document = db.collection_name.find_one(el)
    document_list.append(document)
```

The other way and the better and faster way was to do it like this:

```
my_list = [{'unique_field_id': 1}, {'unique_field_id': 2}, {'unique_field_id': 3}]
my_list_values = [d['unique_field_id'] for d in my_list]
document_list = db.collection_name.find({'unique_field_id': {'$in': my_list_values}})
```

This was working fine with me until unique field of my documents changed to two fields.
Now I have a list of dictionaries with two fields `unique_field_id` and `other_unique_field_id` which are indexed together as the unique field of my document.

If I want to take the first approach it would be like this:

```
my_list = [{'unique_field_id': 1, 'other_unique_field_id': 'a'}, {'unique_field_id': 2, 'other_unique_field_id': 'b'}, {'unique_field_id': 3, 'other_unique_field_id': 'c'}]
document_list = list()
for el in my_list:
    document = db.collection_name.find_one(el)
    document_list.append(document)
```

BUT I need to do it the second way and check the `$in` statement for index of two fields instead of doing it one by one because it is much faster.
How Can I Do It?
Also I think that there is useful answer in this question which I don't understand fully.
[Mongo $in with compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898076/mongo-in-with-compound-index)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$or` operator to find the command.

```
my_list = [
    {'unique_field_id': 1, 'other_unique_field_id': 'a'},
    {'unique_field_id': 2, 'other_unique_field_id': 'b'},
    {'unique_field_id': 3, 'other_unique_field_id': 'c'}
]

document_list = list(db.collection_name.find({
    "$or": my_list
}))
```

Comment: $or performance is not as good as $in check out this link and there are some things about embedding the object and low performance of $or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898076/mongo-in-with-compound-index

Comment: @ArminMz if you go for `$in` it's not possible to match with dictionary pairs