# MongoDB Performance Issue with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, query-optimization, mongoose-schema

I'm looking for some advice on how to improve the performance of my query.

I have this user model in mongoose and I'm indexing **interested_cities**.

```
const firebaseToken = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: "android",
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    device_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    fcm_token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    interested_cities: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            lowercase: true,
            unique: true
        }],
        required: false,
        default: [],
    },
    push_notification_tokens_firebase: {
        type: [firebaseToken],
        required: false,
        default: [],
    },
});

userSchema.index({
    interested_cities: 1
});
```

What I'm looking for is to query the users who have 'A' or 'B' in their array of **interested_cities**.

I'm querying something like this. I only need the firebase fcm_token from the query.

```
const involvedUsers = await User.find(
    {
      $or: [
        { interested_cities: { $in: ['A', 'B'] } },
        { phone_number: { $in: adminPhoneNumbersList } },
      ],
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1,
    }
  );
```

Currently, the query is taking 20 sec for 14k documents, which needs improvements.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Explain:

```
{
                "explainVersion": "1",
                "queryPlanner": {
                    "namespace": "production.users",
                    "indexFilterSet": false,
                    "parsedQuery": {
                        "interested_cities": {
                            "$in": [
                                "A",
                                "B"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
                    "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
                    "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
                    "winningPlan": {
                        "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
                        "transformBy": {
                            "_id": 1,
                            "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1
                        },
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "FETCH",
                            "inputStage": {
                                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern": {
                                    "interested_cities": 1
                                },
                                "indexName": "interested_cities_1",
                                "isMultiKey": true,
                                "multiKeyPaths": {
                                    "interested_cities": [
                                        "interested_cities"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "isUnique": false,
                                "isSparse": false,
                                "isPartial": false,
                                "indexVersion": 2,
                                "direction": "forward",
                                "indexBounds": {
                                    "interested_cities": [
                                        "[\"A\", \"A\"]",
                                        "[\"B\", \"B\"]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans": []
                }
```

```
                "executionStats": {
                    "executionSuccess": true,
                    "nReturned": 6497,
                    "executionTimeMillis": 48,
                    "totalKeysExamined": 0,
                    "totalDocsExamined": 14827,
                    "executionStages": {
                        "stage": "SUBPLAN",
                        "nReturned": 6497,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 46,
                        "works": 14829,
                        "advanced": 6497,
                        "needTime": 8331,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 14,
                        "restoreState": 14,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
                            "nReturned": 6497,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 46,
                            "works": 14829,
                            "advanced": 6497,
                            "needTime": 8331,
                            "needYield": 0,
                            "saveState": 14,
                            "restoreState": 14,
                            "isEOF": 1,
                            "transformBy": {
                                "_id": 1,
                                "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1
                            },
                            "inputStage": {
                                "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                                "filter": {
                                    "$or": [
                                        {
                                            "interested_cities": {
                                                "$in": [
                                                    "A",
                                                    "B"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "phone_number": {
                                                "$in": [
                                                    "phone numbers",
                                                    "phone number"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "nReturned": 6497,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 41,
                                "works": 14829,
                                "advanced": 6497,
                                "needTime": 8331,
                                "needYield": 0,
                                "saveState": 14,
                                "restoreState": 14,
                                "isEOF": 1,
                                "direction": "forward",
                                "docsExamined": 14827
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "allPlansExecution": []
                }
```

Comment: what is len of adminPhoneNumbersList??

Comment: It's around two to three numbers. So max 5 @niko

Comment: [Mongo official docs on scan $in $or operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes), add adminPhoneNumberslist as an index and both lists must be indexed else it ignores the interested_cities index.

Comment: this answer may give a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898076/mongo-in-with-compound-index

Comment: I tried removing phone_number from the query but still got the same amount of time.

Comment: `.find({ interested_cities: { $in: ['A', 'B'] } })` just keep this and check. Remove $or also.

Comment: .find({ interested_cities: { $in: ['A', 'B'] } }) took 22 sec

Comment: Just added .explain(true) output in question

Comment: could you add example how a document with interested_cities look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244774/discussion-between-rutul-patel-and-niko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose optimization:

> By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects, because they have a lot of internal state for change tracking. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean

You can disable this behaviour on per-query basis by appending `.lean()` at the end. If your query is returning "a lot" of documents, this can really improve your speed. You should read more about lean() from the link above.

---

Query optimization:

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will perform a collection scan.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes

Query you shared looks like this:

```
const involvedUsers = await User.find({
  $or: [
    { interested_cities: { $in: citiesArr } },
    { phone_number: { $in: phonesArr } },
  ],
}, { _id: 1, "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1 });
```

Based on the info above, you need to create following two indexes:

```
userSchema.index({ interested_cities: 1 });
userSchema.index({ phone_number: 1 });
```

This way, mongo will be able to "know" which documents are relevant, find them on disk, extract your projection ("_id" and "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token") and return it.

One step further in the optimization would be to create following indexes instead of the ones above:

```
userSchema.index({ interested_cities: 1, _id: 1, "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1 });
userSchema.index({ phone_number: 1, _id: 1, "push_notification_tokens_firebase.fcm_token": 1 });
```

This way, mongo will have all the info it needs to fulfil your query from the indexes, meaning it will never even access the disk to fetch a document.

You can confirm this by running `<your-query>.explain('executionStats')` and confirming that `totalDocsExamined` is `0`.

Read more about executionStats here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.executionStats

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Alex, 
Just following back to this, now this problem becoming worst so I re-tried your solution but in MongoDB you can not have index parallel array. 

so indexing intrested_cities and token array won't work as per your solution